# What is the difference between the Java 1.6 and 1.7 jarsigner

Tags: java-7, java-6, jarsigner

[Just noted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8738962/341091) that you can´t sign Android APKs with the Java 1.7 jarsigner. So I wonder why this is and what is the difference between the 1.6 and 1.7 signer?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the default digest algorithm for Java 1.7 is **SHA-256** while for Java 1.6 it's **SHA1withDSA**.

[Java 1.6 Jarsigner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html#DefaultAlgs)

[Java 1.7 Jarsigner docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html#DefaultAlgs)

Comment: Thanks. Now I just have to find out how to tweak maven to use the right jarsigner and / or the correct sigalg.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you CAN use 1.7!

It is very tricky to find info on the usage with 1.7, but once found it is reasonable simple:

For keytool include

-sigalg SHA1withDSA -keyalg DSA -keysize 1024

For jarsigner include

-sigalg SHA1withDSA -digestalg SHA1

(1024 is the maximum and works, less might do the trick)