# Cacerts compatibility with java versions

Tags: java, keytool, pkix

I am generating **cacerts** using `JDK1.6 keytool`.

Then I am using this cacerts file using `JRE1.7`, but I get exception like :

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.identity.setup.OpenSSOConfigurator.main(OpenSSOConfigurator.java:172)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(Unknown Source)
        ... 22 more
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: signature check failed
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)2015-01-07 19:22:02 IST - ERROR: Problems - bootstrap file not created
```

Is this compatibility issue? Are **cacerts** generated using one version of java not compatible with another version of java?

Comment: It looks like the CA isn't valid in Java 7; perhaps it was revoked.

Comment: @Batty Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281129/jarsigner-verify-works-in-java-6-but-not-java-7)

> The answer to your problem is you are using SUN as your keystore provider java 6 was released prior to oracle purchasing SUN and java 7 was released after and many of the Sun packages are now deprecated.

For full details read the official documentation: [Java Cryptography Architecture Oracle Providers Documentation for Java Platform Standard Edition 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html)