# Setting Up Android Development Env requires a reinstall of Java on Mac, Why?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, installation, eclipse-adt

I'm setting up Android Development Environment on my Macbook Air running OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion.

I have installed JDK for mac by downloading from oracle website.
Then I run `java -version` which shows **java version "1.7.0_13"**

Then I downloaded **ADT bundle for MAC** from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Then I ran eclipse and it shows a install dialog to install java. it says

```
To open “Eclipse,” you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?
```

Why is it asking for java, when I already installed java?

And Java is included in my path too. What went wrong?

Comment: FYI you will need Java 6 (the JDK) at some point, I don't believe Android apps can build with 1.7 alone.  (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578441/can-the-android-sdk-work-with-jdk-1-7)

Comment: I read readme with eclipse and it says that eclipse is tested on JRE 10.6. I guess, It'll cause me problem if I use 10.7. So I Uninstalled 10.7 and installed 10.6. Now Eclipse works.
@Kristopher Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the Android (and Eclipse, apparently..) world hasn't really made the jump to 1.7 yet :-)

Comment: I have 1.7 SE JRE for running eclipse, and 1.6 JDK for building android. Works fine. Android builder can't build application using JDK >= 1.7

Answer (score 0):

- JDK - Java Development Kit
- JRE - Java Runtime Environment
- Java SE - Java Standard Edition

SE defines a set of capabilities and functionalities; there are more complex editions (Enterprise Edition - EE) and simpler ones (Mobile Edition - ME - for mobile environments).

The JDK includes the compiler and other tools needed to develop Java applications; JRE does not. So, to run a Java application someone else provides, you need JRE; to develop a Java application, you need JDK.

So its not a reinstall.

Comment: Please read question again: _To open “Eclipse,” you need a Java SE 6 runtime. Would you like to install one now?_ and he has JRE 1.7 already: _Then I run java -version which shows java version "1.7.0_13"_

Comment: Its not the same Java content, so Yes he needs to install, just do it, what he wants more? Install this and start to work.

Comment: @Marckaraujo running `java -version` gave following output
➜  ~  java -version
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-...

Which clearly shows that I had JRE. btw, I resolved the issue by using JDK 1.6. 

Eclipse readme says that it has been tested to work upto jdk 1.6 on MAC. Readme says that it's tested for Oracle Java 7 Update 2 for windows. I'm using MAC. So Opting for 1.6 is probably right for me and I did that.
on my Mac, Eclipse now works with **java version "1.6.0_37"** :)

Comment: @StarWars, Welcome to the club that uses MAC to develop Android content, just dont forget to make this answer the correct one, may the force be with you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe Eclipse for Mac is broken. I ran into the same problem even though I had just installed Java7. I've used Eclipse ADT with Java7 on my PC before.