# What is the difference between Android 4.4W (API20) and Android L (API20, L Preview) in the SDK Manager?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm updating my SDK Manager in Eclipse, and there are two new downloads:

Android L (API20, L Preview)

Android 4.4W (API20)

I'm confused because they're both referred to as "API 20".  And I'm not sure what the "W" in "4.4W" is referring to.

Comment: L will be the new official release. Its Called L because its Yet unknown which Version Number it will have

Comment: But why is there a 4.4 version that is showing up as API20?

Comment: Very Funny That I did an update yesterday and only to lunch the SDK manager few hours later an see the two new Android 4.4W and Android L. was kind of confused also

Answer (score 87, accepted):

[L Developer Preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html) is the preview of Android 5.0

[Android 4.4W](http://developer.android.com/wear/index.html) is Android Wear SDK

Comment: Thanks, was really confused also, but why release two update together with the same api level and yet don't know the name to give one of it

Comment: As per new project created from template in Android Studio (contains `values-21` folder with `android:Theme.Material.Light`), the "L" SDK when released will have the number "21".

Comment: @Venom Vendor Considering their naming conventions(mostly related to sugar edibles or toffees) from the past are they naming it to Lollipop for Android 5.0

Comment: @user285oo6 But there is no official confirmation for that. for 4.X it was assumed to be `Key Lime Pie` but it is actually `KitKat`.

Comment: If I want to target to the new Android "L", what should I put in the manifest? When I put "20" it says it's for 4.4W , but when I set it to "L", it wants me to set the minSdk to it too.

Comment: @androiddeveloper `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="L" android:targetSdkVersion="L" />` in Gradle `compileSdkVersion "android-L"`

Comment: @VenomVendor Yes that's what it wants me to do (as I wrote), but it never wanted it before. Why would I want to set minSdk to it? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Apparently Android "L" requires JDK 7.  It's about time.

Comment: Given the present confusion (which I had as well), I'm guessing that the "L" preview will eventually end up as API level 21 (or greater). Again guessing, I would say there was some confusion / conflict between different groups at Google that created the existing situation.

Comment: I have a question regarding Android 4.4W : Is it possible to install any app there? It seems that the developer console shows me some users have installed my app there (and didn't even uninstall it!), but I never checked how it works there. The app was barely even tested on tablets... Here's the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager . How could it be? If I found it doesn't work well, can I block users from installing it on Android wear? I don't want them to give bad reviews because of this...

Comment: @androiddeveloper See here http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html under the heading "Installing the JDK"

Comment: @jdj interesting. Thank you. Do note that not all v7 features of Java are supported on all Android versions : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21700827

Comment: @JDJ I actually work with v6 of Java at the office (not my choice, things move slowly sometimes), and it works fine. Seems like an odd thing. I've also found this website that says v6 is ok : https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i . I think that what you've found is for compiling the OS itself...

Answer (score 6):

Android 4.4W Target Android Watches

See Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztzXa.jpg

while Android L (API20, L Preview) is the preview of the upcoming release of Android. It is subject to change and it's stability is not guaranteed

Answer (score 2):

Android Lollipop is API 21 , so this is possible to differentiate between them:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

Android 4.4W is for Android Wear (mostly smart watches).