# Splitting a String works in Java, doesn't work on Android

Tags: java, android, regex, string

So I have this logic which splits a String by 4 characters each. Something like this

```
0108011305080508000000 gives 0108 0113 0508 0508 0000 00
```

The logic I used is

```
String [] splitErrorCode = inputString.split("(?<=\\G....)");
```

It works great in Java, but when I run it in Android I get the wrong output.

`0108 011305080508000000`

I have no clue what is going wrong.
After a going through the String's split function, I realized Android uses `fastSplit` where as the Java version has a huge splitting logic.

Aren't both the functions supposed to work identically? Why is this a problem? Any comments/ suggestions?

Comment: Great question (+1). I'm amazed that a method as basic as `split` can behave differently in android and Java. Does anyone know where there is a list of differences? I would ask it as a question, but I know it would be closed in seconds.

Answer (score 4):

[`\G` in Java was added in Java 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to mimic the Perl construct:

> http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#What-good-is-%5CG-in-a-regular-expression:
>
> > You use the \G anchor to start the next match on the same string where the last match left off.

Support for this was very poor. [This construct is documented in Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) to be used in negative variable-length lookbehinds to limit how far back the lookbehind goes. Explicit support was added.

However, the split method in JDK 7 has a fast path for the common case where the limit is a single character. This avoids the need to compile or to use regex. Here is the method (detail source redacted):

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    /* fastpath if the regex is a
     (1)one-char String and this character is not one of the
        RegEx's meta characters ".$|()[{^?*+\\", or
     (2)two-char String and the first char is the backslash and
        the second is not the ascii digit or ascii letter.
     */
    char ch = 0;
    if (((regex.value.length == 1 &&
         ".$|()[{^?*+\\".indexOf(ch = regex.charAt(0)) == -1) ||
         (regex.length() == 2 &&
         /* Fast path checks as documented in the comment */ )
    {
        // Fast path computation redacted!
        String[] result = new String[resultSize];
        return list.subList(0, resultSize).toArray(result);
    }
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

And before:

```
public String[] split(String regex, int limit) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).split(this, limit);
}
```

While this fastpath exists, note that [**deploying Android programs means it must have source compatibility with Java 6**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567402/3622940). The Android environment is unable to take advantage of the fast path, therefore it delegates to `fastSplit` and loses some of the Perl construct supports, such as `\A`.

As for why they didn't like the traditional always-regex path, it's kind of obvious by itself.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of splitting like you do (and by the way this will recompile a pattern for each split operation) just do it like this; it's more simple and performs better:

```
private static final Pattern ONE_TO_FOUR_DIGITS = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,4}");

// ...

public List<String> splitErrorCodes(final String input)
{
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>(input.length() / 4 + 1);
    final Matcher m = ONE_TO_FOUR_DIGITS.matcher(input);

    while (m.find())
        ret.add(m.group());

    return ret;
}
```

Of course, an additional check would need to be performed on the shape of `input` as a whole but it's really not hard to do. Left as an exercise ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton @fge. Your solution is working great, Would eventually mark your answer as accepted. Waiting for people to comment on why such a simple split method has different implementations,and doesn't work on android.