# Android: Unable to install release build onto emulator; getting Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]

Tags: android

I am able to install a debug build onto emulator doing:

```
ant debug install
```

but am unable to install a release build. My steps:

```
1. ant release
2. jarsigner -verbose -keystore ..\my-release-key.keystore bin\myapp-release-unsigned.apk mykey
3. ren bin\myapp-release-unsigned.apk bin\myapp-release-signed.apk
4. zipalign -v 4 myapp-release-signed.apk myapp-release.apk
5. adb install bin\myapp-release.apk
```

All steps run successfully except the last one where I get a message:

```
82 KB/s (388012 bytes in 4.613s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/myapp-release.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]
```

I have also tried doing `ant installr` instead of `adb install bin\myapp-release.apk` with the same result

EDIT: I think this has to do with the key, since that is the only difference I can see between release and debug builds. I generated the key using:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

as mentioned on http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html. I modified `ant.properties` file per http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/building/building-cmdline.html and now just doing `ant release install` (instead of the steps above) but still running into same problem. If someone knows how does ant generate the debug key, then I could follow same procedure to generate my release key and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: have you uninstalled your debug build app?

Comment: yes I have uninstalled debug build

Comment: just install the unsigned apk.

Comment: There may be an issue with your certificate. Try generating a new one. Also try installing release version both on device and on emulator, if error is consistent, than this is not a device glitch.

Comment: This can be caused by an error in your AndroidManifest.xml file (for instance, if your version code isn't an integer, as described [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-beginners/LxgAIHETEWg).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8225017/147530
Notes:
1. I was getting a INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION. I did not get a INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES
2. Running `adb logcat` from cmd line showed stacktrace similar to that in [Android signing with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036422/android-signing-with-ant):

```
W/PackageParser(   51): Exception reading /data/app/vmdl24231.tmp
W/PackageParser(   51): java.lang.SecurityException: META-INF/METALLIC.SF has in
valid digest for assets/myasset.xtx in /data/app/vmdl24231.tmp
W/PackageParser(   51):         at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.verifyCertificate(J
arVerifier.java:370)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.readCertificates(Ja
rVerifier.java:273)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.
java:416)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.loadCertific
ates(PackageParser.java:317)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at android.content.pm.PackageParser.collectCerti
ficates(PackageParser.java:479)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.inst
allPackageLI(PackageManagerService.java:4287)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService.acce
ss$1600(PackageManagerService.java:109)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at com.android.server.PackageManagerService$5.ru
n(PackageManagerService.java:3779)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.jav
a:587)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:92)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
W/PackageParser(   51):         at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.ja
va:60)
```

References:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19567

Comment: thanks, using the logcat was important to get the detail, I had the same one.

Answer (score 11):

I had this same issue because I was using a string value in my AndroidManifest.xml file like this:

```
android:versionCode="@string/version_code"
android:versionName="@string/version_name"
```

Where strings.xml contained:

```
<string name="version_code">3</string>
<string name="version_name">1.0</string>
```

`versionCode` should be an integer.  Once I took out that `@string` reference I no longer got this error and the application compiled and ran just fine:

```
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

Comment: You can store `versionCode` as integer: `<integer name="version_code">3</integer>` and refer as `@integer/version_code`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, but when I looked in logcat while trying to install the apk file to the phone, I've seen these lines:

> 11-10 11:28:26.971 20075 20085 D         : Zip: EOCD not found,
>   /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk is
>   not zip
>
> 11-10 11:28:26.972 20075 20085 W zipro   : Error opening archive
>   /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk:
>   Invalid file
>
> 11-10 11:28:26.972 20075 20085 D asset   : failed to open Zip archive
>   '/data/local/tmp/myapp.apk'
>
> 11-10 11:28:26.972 20075 20085 W DefContainer: Failed to parse package
>   at /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk:
>   android.content.pm.PackageParser$PackageParserException: Failed to
>   parse
>   /data/local/tmp/myapp.apk

As mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20327849/997940), turned out the apk file was corrupted (probably didn't download correctly), so I had to download it again, then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer in this one.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/96497

AndroidManifest.xml is missing one line of code:

android:exported="true"

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:exported="true" -> this is the missing line of code
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        >
```