# Flutter Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]

Tags: android, flutter

Recently, I used Flutter to reconstruct the previous Android project, but it could not be installed on some Android phones. The following is an error message:

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1 Performing Streamed Install db: failed to install .../build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:Failure[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]Error launching application on V2036A.
```

Below is the information about flutter doctor-v：

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.3, on macOS 11.5.1 20G80 darwin-arm, locale
zh-Hans-CN)
• Flutter version 2.5.3 at /Users/gengyibin/Documents/flutter
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
• Framework revision 18116933e7 (3 months ago), 2021-10-15 10:46:35 -0700
• Engine revision d3ea636dc5
• Dart version 2.14.4
• Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
• Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
• Android SDK at /Users/gengyibin/Library/Android/sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 31.0.0
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android
  Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• Xcode 13.1, Build version 13A1030d
• CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
   https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
• VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
• Flutter extension can be installed from:
   https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799689/android-unable-to-install-release-build-onto-emulator-getting-failure-install

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I tried to create a new empty FLUTTER project that was still running on the same phone and encountered the same error. I am not sure whether it is the flutter or the phone‘s question