# Ant Build Signing Jar

Tags: android, ant, java-7, jar-signing, jarsigner

I'm still getting the following error message when I try to install on the Android device.

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

I updated Ant to the latest version 1.8.3 that addresses this issue when used with Java 7.
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52344

I'm using the build.xml file in the project to create the release APK file.
My ANT_HOME path is set correctly in the Windows->Preference

Any ideas?

Comment: In what environment are you programming? (signing is easier in Eclipse)

Comment: I'm using Eclipse in Windows.  It works fine if I use the Export from Eclipse. I want to use the automatied Ant build feature and thats when it fails with the jarsigner.

Comment: Gotcha--I'm afraid I can't help you there, but I upvoted your question.

Comment: if you solved the question, please post the solution as an answer and accept it (as soon as it is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have to add the following in the /tools/ant/build.xml

```
<signjar
    sigalg="MD5withRSA"
    digestalg="SHA1">
```

Comment: Thank you, but your solution wokrs for ant-1.8.3 where issue was fixed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539794/310760 for fully answer.

Answer (score 0):

Override the release-sign target by copying the target from sdk build.xml and replace the signapk with signjar and add the above 2 arguments