# Publishing Proguarded Android Application using ANT

Tags: android, ant, proguard

We're using Android SDK Tools 19  and Android ADT Plugin 18, If we're publishing Application through ANT, we're getting Application Not Installed when trying to install that application.

I also wanted to know how to use Proguard with Android Application which uses Recent ADT plugin, SDK tools.

We're Using Windows 7,JDK 1.7.0, Eclipse For Android Application Development.
We came to know that  JDK 7 (1.7.0) so try adding these options when signing with jarsigner: -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg MD5withRSA
    And Replaced the following property of Tools->ANT->BuildJar->Signjar

```
<signjar
                        jar="${out.packaged.file}"
                        signedjar="${out.unaligned.file}"
                        keystore="${key.store}"
                        storepass="${key.store.password}"
                        alias="${key.alias}"
                        keypass="${key.alias.password}"
                        verbose="${verbose}" />

with these properties 

 <signjar
                        sigalg="MD5withRSA"
                        digestalg="SHA1"
                        jar="${out.packaged.file}"
                        signedjar="${out.unaligned.file}"
                        keystore="${key.store}"
                        storepass="${key.store.password}"
                        alias="${key.alias}"
                        keypass="${key.alias.password}"
                        verbose="${verbose}" /> 

as per [blog]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036422/android-signing-with-ant
```

I am also using GSON Library,Http Mime Library,Android v4 Fragment.
So after publishing,it will be published and even the application is reduced.But if i'm trying to run the published Application if it is showing Forceful Close of Application

Answer (score 0):

If you use the default `build.xml` provided in the Android SDK and specify target as release, you can get proguard applied release apk file.

To get `build.xml`, run `android update project` command.

To make a release build, you should prepare release key and proguard.cfg file.