# Just started Java, should I continue with 7 or 6, to code for Android?

Tags: java, android

As the title describes, I started learning Java, from various sources(currently a playlist on youtube). I have JDK 7 installed.

The question is, is there anything I would learn using java 7 as a starter that wouldn't work on 6? Is there any major difference with the language?

The Language Specicifation and various things I found on the web were too hard to understand.

Comment: "The Language Specicifation and various things I found on the web were too hard to understand" --- I mean, too advanced stuff..

Comment: You have JDK 7; stick with JDK 7.  Simple as that :)  Book recommendation for Android: [Android Application Development, Darcey & Conder](http://www.amazon.com/Teach-Yourself-Android-Application-Development/dp/0672335697)

Comment: Added the book to my reading list, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Officially, JDK 7 "isn't supported" for Android

2) No biggie - JDK 7 should work fine with Android anyway.  Just go into Eclipse and set compatibility for "Java 6".

3) There's also one minor issue with .jar signing.  It's probably already fixed in the latest Eclipse/Ant combination (Eclipse 4.2/Juno), but the workaround is here:

- [Android signing with Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036422/android-signing-with-ant)

4) BOTTOM LINE: If you've got JDK 7, then just keep JDK 7.

Comment: I have the latest Eclipse for Mobile Developers with android addons installed, the "Compiler Compliance level" is set to 1.6 as default, is this the thing you tell me to do in the second? Thanks a lot by the way, this was the answer I needed.

Comment: @g_kaya - yes, that's exactly what I meant.  Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

the Android SDK is Java 6 compliant, and not Java 7. learning Java 7 specific language features is not going to benefit you if you plan to code to the Android SDK.

the Android SDK has much in common w/ the JDK, but it's not the same thing. some things are missing, and some things are added. if you want to develop on android, get the Android SDK. then there's no question.

Answer (score 1):

Learn the latest, saves mental translations.

I learnt Java some years back and found Ivor Horton's Beginning Java a very useful reference which I have kept forever!. I see that he is up to Java 7 Edition http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Ivor-Horton-s-Beginning-Java-Java-7-Edition.productCd-0470404140.html

The appeal of the Wrox series of book is that you can download the code examples which is a useful reference even if you dont by the book. Look up the chapter outline and you can work out what the author showing.

If you are ok with reading code, just download the examples.

Good luck.

Comment: Got the codes and other stuff.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

JDK is the current standard version; 6 and 5 have reached the end of their support life.

By all means proceed with JDK 7.